# Why do I need to call methods on function expression when working with emscripten?

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I'm working through some JavaScript code (emscriptem running inside a webworker) trying to understand what is happening.

I've stumbled over this snippet:

```
// console polyfill for emscripted Module
var console = {};

console.log = (function() {

  return function(str) {
    master.postMessage({type: 'log', sentence: str});
  };
}());
```

and am clueless as to why a function expression has to be called immediately. I have no experience with emscriptem, so maybe this is a requirement but I have not delved deep into the documentation and on first glance did not come up with something that made sense to me.

**Question:**
Why do I need to call methods on function expression when working with emscripten?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have function declarations. What are you talking about?

Comment: why is the method called like this upon declaration `var x = (function () {...}(why?))`

Comment: What method and what declaration?

Comment: @melpomene "JavaScript doesn't have function declarations"...isn't `function a() {}` a function declaration (as opposed to a function expression)?

Comment: @melpommene - sorry for my wrong use of words. I checked MDN, there is Function constructor, function declaration and function expression. I should have written expressions - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression

Comment: @Daniel_L Oh, interesting. The description of the `function-declaration` tag says: "*the process of describing the type and identifier of a function.*" (This would be something like `int foo(void);` in C or `bar :: String -> Int` in Haskell.) I'd call `function a() {}` a function definition in that context. But you're right that the ECMAScript spec uses a different definition. Still, the tag doesn't really apply and the posted code only contains function expressions.

Comment: thanks for removing the tag. I updated the question and title. I would still appreciate and answer. thx

Comment: I don't understand "need to call methods". What method call are you referring to?

Comment: `console.log`. "normally" in Javascript I would write `console.log = function () {...};` and call it when needed. But the code above uses `console.log = (function () {...}())` which in Javascript calls `console.log` immediately. I don't know why this is necessary - hence my question.

Comment: No, it doesn't call `console.log` immediately. It calls `function () { ... }`.

Comment: and is this always necessary when expressing JavaScript methods when writing code to work with emscripten?

Comment: No, someone decided to box it. All that is happening is the author wanted to force a scope... For no apparent reason

Comment: Thanks @rlemon . I'll take that until I find another reason, which I don't believe there is.